# Combine 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql, group-by, odbc, db2

I'm stuck on a SQL issue, I'm almost sure it's all easy but I can't find a proper answer. Below here is the example. I want to combine those 2 queries :

```
SELECT 
    num_rata, SUM(val_imp*0.01) AS amount 
FROM table1
WHERE 
    col1 <> 0
    AND num_contract = 88
GROUP BY num_rata
```

That returns something like :

```
1   215.00
2   220.00
3   210.00
4   115.00
5   315.00
```

And :

```
SELECT 
    num_rata, SUM(val_ban*0.01) AS amount
FROM table2
WHERE 
    num_contract = 2988
GROUP BY num_rata;
```

Example result set :

```
1   15.00
2   615.00
3   275.00
4   285.00
5   285.00
6   275.00
7   260.00
8   215.00
9   215.00
```

As a final result I would like something like this :

```
1   215.00 15.00
2   220.00 615.00
3   210.00 275.00
4   115.00 285.00
5   315.00 285.00
6          275.00
7          260.00
8          215.00 
9          215.00
```

Thank you for any hint.

fabien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either a union or an outer join - I would prefer a union, like this:

```
SELECT num_rata, sum(val_imp)*0.01 imp_amount, sum(val_ban)*0.01 ban_amount
from (SELECT num_rata, val_imp, 0 val_ban
      FROM table1
      WHERE col1 <> 0 AND num_contract = 88
      UNION ALL
      SELECT num_rata, 0 val_imp, val_ban
      FROM table2
      WHERE num_contract = 2988) v
GROUP BY num_rata;
```

Comment: @feub, Which bit don't you get? Also, have you tried running it (or is the real situation more complicated)?

Comment: For example, in `SELECT num_rata, val_imp, 0 val_ban`, i don't get the syntax `0 val_ban`. And the `v` is a typo? Thank you.

Comment: @feub, in `select ..., 0 val_ban from ...` val_ban is a column alias - so the query is selecting the constant value 0 as the value val_ban. This could have been formatted as `select ..., 0 as val_ban from ...`, although the `as` is optional. The `v` is a table alias - some dialects of SQL (such as MySQL) require a table alias for an inline view, some don't.

Comment: thank you so much, yes it works ;] I knew for the alias, but not for assigning a value like this with 0. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select 
    t1.num_rata, 
    SUM(t1.val_imp*0.01) AS amount1,
    SUM(t2.val_ban*0.01) AS amount2
from
    table1 t1 right outer join table2 t2 on t1.num_rata=t2.num_rata
where
    t1.col1<>0 and
    t1.num_contract = 88 and 
    t2.num_contract = 2988
GROUP BY t1.num_rata
```

Comment: I agree with it being an outer join issue, but I feel that it should be a right outer join, because she needs all the records from the second table. See here some examples with left and right outer joins: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: I agree, thanks... too early in the morning - need more coffeeeeee....:-) (fixed my answer above)

Comment: Potentially, a full outer join. Also, you appear to be assuming that where there are multiple records for a given num_rata on one table, there will never be more than one record for the same num_rata on the other table - otherwise, the SUMs will be inflated. Assuming the tables each have their own unique ID field, you could fix it by changing `SUM(t1.val_imp*0.01)` to `SUM(t1.val_imp*0.01)/COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(t2.id,1))`, and vice versa for val_ban.

Comment: Mark Bannister is right, multiple records for a given num_rata on the other table is possible. Unfortunately, that outer join doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try what will this do:

```
SELECT num_rata, (
    coalesce(
        (SELECT SUM(val_imp*0.01) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.num_rata = foo.num_rata)
    ,0)
) as col1, (
    coalesce(
        (SELECT SUM(val_ban*0.01) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.num_rata = foo.num_rata)
    ,0)
) as col2 FROM
(
    (SELECT num_rata FROM table1 WHERE col1 <> 0 AND num_contract = 88)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT num_rata FROM table2 WHERE num_contract = 2988)
) as foo;
```

I might have syntax error (I am writing this from a university lecture), but this (or similar) should do the trick.